# Wrap int pointer member variable in boost.python/pyplusplus

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python, py++

If I am using boost.python or pyplusplus, how do I wrap an int pointer, or any pointer that is a member variable of a class?

For example, how would I wrap `x` from the following class:

```
class Foo{
    int * x;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to expose the class and properties to Python.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mylib)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<Foo>("Foo")
        .def_readwrite("x", &Foo::x);
}
```

Invoking the class in Python is similarly simple.

```
>>> import mylib
>>> fooObj = mylib.Foo()
>>> fooObj.x = 3
>>> print 'fooObj.x is ', fooObj.x
fooObj.x is 3
```

Comment: When I tried this, I've got:ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    None.None(Foo, int)
did not match C++ signature:
    None(Foo {lvalue}, int*)

Comment: Also, if you try to read the variable, you get: 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: int*`